psycopg2 cannot find an existing table
I'm trying to setup a toy database with PostgreSQL and read a table using psycopg2 in Python, but psycopg2 cannot find an existing table.
When running the following code
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="example_db",
    user="my_user",
    password="my_pw"
)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
rows = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()

I got the error
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "employees" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM employees

The table can be found though if I directly connect to the PostgreSQL server from commandline
$ psql -U my_user -d example_db
psql (12.18 (Ubuntu 12.18-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

example_db=# SELECT * FROM employees;
 id |     name     | age | position
----+--------------+-----+-----------
  1 | John Doe     |  30 | Manager
  2 | Jane Smith   |  25 | Developer
  3 | Mike Johnson |  35 | Designer
(3 rows)

I am using WSL with Ubuntu-20.04 distribution.

Edit:
Here are the available database
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql (12.18 (Ubuntu 12.18-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))

postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 example_db | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
            |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres+
            |          |          |         |         | my_user=CTc/postgres
 postgres   | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 template0  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)


Are you 100% confident to connect the same database in both case?

Could the table be in another schema? Does your user have permission to see the table (you use a different user with psql)?

@jlandercy The prompt on psql shows that the database is example_db. Is there a way to verify if psycopg2.connect actually connected to example_db as requested? I've added the list of databases in the post, and I don't see anything suspecious.

@snakecharmerb Both psycopg2.connect and psql used the same user (my_user).

I meant you don't have two setup on postresql? One on windows and a second on wsl?

psql -U my_user -d example_db and psycopg2.connect(host="localhost" ,database="example_db", user="my_user",    password="my_pw") could potentially be connecting to different instances as the first is using a local socket and the second the network loopback IP 127.0.0.1. Make your connection parameters the same and see what happens.

Are you able to connect to the database through pgAdmin and check the database through the GUI?
Check which schema that database is under, and try adding that to the query as below:
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM schema_here.employees")

Usually new database instances are in 'public' schema but you can also specify a schema name other than 'public'.
